# Linear regression with Pytorch not converging

Tags: neural-network, linear-regression, pytorch, implementation, mlp

I am trying to perform a simple linear regression using Pytorch lightning (a network with only one neuron). The network is supposed to learn a simple function: `y=-4x`.
The size of my dataset is 1000 and contains points from the line `y=-4x` with a small amount of gaussian noise. The dataset looks like this:
[image]
I am facing a strange problem where the model only converges when the batch size is small enough **and** when I don't shuffle random data in each batch.
Shown in the graph below is the slope, intercept and final train loss that the model converged to after 100 epochs, as a function of the batch size, when the data is not shuffled:
[image: Data not shuffled]
We can see that the model converges to the right solution only when the batch size is small enough (the right solution is intercept=0 and slope=-4).

Shown below is the same experiment, but this time I used shuffled data in each batch:
[image]
We can see that the model didn't even converge to the right solution, regardless of the batch size!

Below is the code used to generate the results for this experiment:

```
import torch
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
from torch.nn import functional as F
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class LineFunction(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, a, b, n, x0=0, x1=1, noise=0):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b
        self._x = torch.linspace(x0, x1, n, requires_grad=False)
        self._x = self._x.unsqueeze(1)
        self._noise = torch.distributions.normal.Normal(torch.tensor([0.0]), torch.tensor([1.0])).sample((n,)) * noise
        self._noise = self._noise.unsqueeze(1)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._x)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        x = self._x[idx]
        y = self._a * x + self._b + self._noise[idx]
        return x, y


class LinReg(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer_1 = torch.nn.Linear(1, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layer_1(x)

    def training_step(self, train_batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = train_batch
        preds = self.forward(x)
        loss = F.mse_loss(preds, y)
        self.log('train_loss', loss)
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, val_batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = val_batch
        preds = self.forward(x)
        loss = F.mse_loss(preds, y)
        self.log('val_loss', loss)

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=1e-2)
        return optimizer


batch_sizes = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(10, 1000, 100)]
slopes = []
intercepts = []
train_loss = []
shuffle = True

for batch_size in batch_sizes:
    train_dataloader = DataLoader(LineFunction(-4, 0, 1000, noise=0.05), batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle)
    test_dataloader = DataLoader(LineFunction(-4, 0, 1000, noise=0.05), batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle)

    model = LinReg()
    trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=100)
    trainer.fit(model, train_dataloader, test_dataloader)
    slopes.append(float(model.layer_1.weight.data))
    intercepts.append(float(model.layer_1.bias.data))
    train_loss.append(trainer.logged_metrics['train_loss'])


fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, figsize=(15, 10))
for ax, measure, measure_name in zip(axes, [slopes, intercepts, train_loss], ['slope', 'intercept', 'train_loss']):
    ax.set_xlabel('batch size')
    ax.set_ylabel(measure_name)
    ax.plot(batch_sizes, measure)

plt.show()
```

I am kind of stumped here. Why does this simple model not always converge? I also tried experimenting with different learning rates but that didn't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: Using a learning rate of 2e-2 and a batch size of 128 is working for me as it allows the model to reach a loss less than 0.003 after 150 epochs with a slope and intercept close to the real values (-3.9440 and -0.0303 respectively).